# Extra permissions are being added to apk and bundle

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm encountering very strange problem. When I build apk or bundle dangerous permissions like write external storage is being added to manifest. I found out it when wanted to publish on play store, it gave me that warning. After extracting bundle I looked at manifest file and there were bunch of permissions which I don't use in my app.

Have anyone had this issue ever?

Comment: So you mean to say you haven't mentioned those permissions in Manifest file that you have in code. But after creating the bundle when you extract and see the same manifest file permissions are there?

Comment: Have you checked other third party lib uses that permission?

Comment: @gprathour Yes, exactly

Comment: @RonakMakwana how to check it? I'm using firebase, facebook sdk etc

Comment: @support_ms Open your Manifest file and check tab at bottom, "Merged Manifest", there u can find permissions which is used by you and by other libs.

Comment: Are you targeting Q, and are you writing to any files? https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#permissions

Comment: @RonakMakwana I looked at merged manifest. There is text in front of write external storage permission: Implied from the app main manifest (this file), line 1; reason: com.android.installreferrer has a targetSdkVersion < 4.  My target SDK 28

Comment: There you go. so find lib that uses that permission and remove it if you want to remove permissions from your manifest.

Comment: That target sdk version is for that particular lib not for your app.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for everyone who directed me to the right place. So, the reason is because some of 3rd party libs used that permissions. There will be two options in this case:

1. Remove 3rd party lib which is using dangerous permission
2. In AndroidManifest.xml file add the following:

> ```
> <uses-permission
>     android:name="android.permission.SomePermission"
>     tools:node="remove" />
> ```

During build process this will remove permission from final bundle or apk.